# WordPress Duplicate term_id resulting in MultiSite Errors

Tags: php, wordpress

We have some users that have added the same tag and category to a blog. When they do this, they are unable to edit or use those tags / categories and receive an error basically stating “You need a higher level of permission.”

So far i've determined the actual error being thrown is `Term ID is shared between multiple taxonomies` error that we have been receiving when trying to edit / delete certain post categories or post tags.

Debugging this further, the issue seems to be happening at creation time.  When I look at the tables in the database the terms table looks fine, but the term_taxonomy table does not.  The same `term_id` is being saved for both entries.

```
MariaDB [wordpress]> select * from wp_62_terms;
+---------+-----------------------+-----------------------+------------+
| term_id | name                  | slug                  | term_group |
+---------+-----------------------+-----------------------+------------+
|       1 | Uncategorized         | uncategorized         |          0 |
|       2 | Blogroll              | blogroll              |          0 |
|  107691 | ppppp                 | ppppp                 |          0 |
|  107692 | ppppp                 | ppppp                 |          0 |
+---------+-----------------------+-----------------------+------------+

MariaDB [wordpress]> select * from wp_62_term_taxonomy;
+------------------+---------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------+
| term_taxonomy_id | term_id | taxonomy      | description | parent | count |
+------------------+---------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------+
|                1 |       1 | category      |             |      0 |    19 |
|                2 |       2 | link_category |             |      0 |     0 |
|               34 |  107691 | post_tag      |             |      0 |     0 |
|               35 |  107691 | category      |             |      0 |     0 |
+------------------+---------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------+
```

I have been debugging this further and captured the `$wpdb->last_query` value for that able insert and those read as follows:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_62_term_taxonomy` (`term_id`, `taxonomy`, `description`, `parent`, `count`) VALUES (107691, 'post_tag', '', 0, 0)

INSERT INTO `wp_62_term_taxonomy` (`term_id`, `taxonomy`, `description`, `parent`, `count`) VALUES (107692, 'category', '', 0, 0)
```

The INSERT sql shows the correct `term_id` however - that is not what is getting stored in the database.

Manually updating the database value does correct the problem.

Any thoughts / ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by what seems to be a legacy and a potentially unused feature of WordPress Multisite.  When the `global_terms_enabled` value is enabled in the `wp_sitemeta` table, it will create a global term list in the `wp_sitecategories` table.

Within the `wp-includes\ms-functions.php` file, the `global_terms` function is called when a new taxonomy term is added.  Within that function, it does a check in the `wp_sitecategories` table to see if that term exists.  However - that logic in that function is flawed and does not account for the same value across multiple taxonomies.  It detects it as a duplicate, and then issues wpdb queries to change the `term_id` values as noted above.

This was logged as a bug in the WordPress Core here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/55979

Changing the sitemeta value of `global_terms_enabled` from `1` to `0` solved this behavior.